# UNIX: rename files piped from find command

Tags: unix, find, rename, flags, locked

I basically want to add a string to all the files in a directory that are locked. I'm having trouble passing the filenames to a `mv` command:

```
find . -flags uchg -exec chflags nouchg "{}" | mv "{}" "{}"_LOCK \;
```

The above code obviously doesnt work but I think it explains what I'm trying to do.

I'm facing two problems:

1. Adding a string to the end of a filename but before the extension (`001_LOCK.jpg`).
2. Passing the output of the `find` command twice. I need to do this because it won't let me change the names of the files while they are locked. So I need to unlock the file and then rename it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to do this with a scripting language, like Python. I can't imagine parsing filenames for extensions in `bash` or `awk`...

Comment: Blender, I could add the "LOCK" before the filename if need be but when i do that, it looks like this: LOCK./001.jpg.  It seems to be piping the file path from find. Is there a way to pass just "001.jpg" instead of "./001.jpg"?

Comment: mu is too short, I am working with hundreds of files at a time.

Comment: Is the extension always `.jpg`?  Are you using Bash or Korn or Bourne or ... which shell are you using?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, the extension is usually .nef but sometimes .jpg. I'm using Bash (default mac).

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a good start.

I assume you do not pipe chflags to mv, which doesn't make sense, but just rename the file if chflags fails. Processing the extension is more tricky but is certainly doable.

```
find . -flags uchg -exec sh -c "chflags nouchg \$0 || mv \$0 \$0_LOCK" {} \;
```

*Edit: rename if chflags **succeeds**:*

```
find . -flags uchg -exec sh -c "chflags nouchg \$0 && mv \$0 \$0_LOCK" {} \;
```

Comment: I actually need it to rename the file after chflags succeeds. the only reason that Im unlocking the files is so that I can rename them. I'm not trying to pipe chflags to mv, but trying to pipe the result of "find * -flags uchg" to both "chflags nouchg" and "mv"

Comment: jlliagre, this solves problem #2. Thanks! This way still adds the LOCK after the file extension, but I'm not too worried about that. I changed it to the following in order to put the string at the beginning: find * -flags uchg -exec sh -c "chflags nouchg \$0 && mv \$0 LOCK\$0" {} \;